# What is inverse inequality in functional/numerical analysis or finite element methods?

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, numerical-methods, normed-spaces, finite-element-method

I have tried to find out the answer by searching but there is no Wiki page like the introduction to [trace inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_inequalities). Roughly I know the inverse inequality is something like $\|\nabla v\| \lesssim h \|v\|$ but I really want to know more details, and the reason why it is called "inverse".

Answer (score 0):

Poincare's inequality says:

$$||v||_{L^2(\Omega)} \leq C(\Omega)||\nabla v||_{L^2(\Omega)}~~ \forall v\in H_0^1(\Omega)  $$ 
but for quasi-uniform triangulation, we have
$$||\nabla v_h||_{L^2} \leq Ch^{-1}|| v_h||_{L^2}, $$

these kinds of estimates are called inverse estimates for the apparent reason that they provide inverse relation to norms.